# CiviMail: How can I retarget the non-opens and/or non-clicks in CiviCRM?

Tags: civimail, groups

Right now I am exploring CiviCRM as a new CRM for my non profit organization. We have a whole wish list, and one crucial wish is to be able to send new emails to a non-opens and/or non-clicks group. We saw the report option, but can we use the groups in the report to make a new group to send email to? We cannot find the answer. Not in the test installation nor in the user guide. Thank you so much for your help! It's a crucial feature for us. Best, Anne

Answer (score 1):

While we dont use it for privacy reasons it should be perfectly doable. Reports usually have the option to add its resulting contacts to a group.

If you dont mind german here is a screenshot from a mailing report for demo mailing with tracking:

[image: Mailing Report]

Each link provides a report/search with a selected subset of contacts.

Additionally you can use the extended search to define your target group however you like and create groups or smart groups from there.

Comment: Dear Thomas, Thank you so much! Good to know we can just use this subset of contacts again to create new smart groups!